# Hadoop / EMR - s3 logs do not match actual row count

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, emr, amazon-emr

I'm trying to find out more information about an AWS/EMR problem. Our log file on s3 is reporting 25,000 rows written, a row count of the results is showing 23,000 ish. We think it attempts to write 25,000 but doesn't fully complete, but only sometimes. Its not reproducible - re-running the same script with the same inputs gets the full 25,000 into the output file.

I can't ask AWS support directly because support for AWS costs money, and without being able to reproduce that makes it hard to phrase the question. It only happens on small small jobs never when the inputs/outputs to process are average-sized or large.

*guesses:*

- maybe it is shutting down the cluster too soon?
- the log file is not wrong - the log file shows a higher number than what ends up in the output.. re-running the job exactly the same way yields the full result with no rows lost instead, for no apparent reason. Einstein's definition of insanity. But that number is the desired/expected number - the output is missing some 2k rows (the log reports the correct number).

How can I find out more information about this bug, or any advice to avoid this bug. It seems like an error within AWS / EMR itself

Comment: can you explain a little bit more of what the 25,000 rows are? is that 25,000 items in an RDD? or 25,000 rows of log output?

Comment: @Kristian 25,000 is a row count of the .tar.gz output file, and the number reported for "row count" in the emr console

Comment: we're running hive and ami 3.11 and we're writing gzipped text shards to s3

Comment: strange. i feel like you might want to try this same work in spark, and see if the problem happens there too